# How to save text into variable with selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I a trying to save a order number from a page into a variable and then display it

```
Purchase Order 234 has been
```

Is there a way of just getting the number "234"?

The HTML

```
<div class="GD">
<div class="GD1">Purchase Order 234 has been logged on 8/28/2014.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd have to see the HTML to be certain, but assuming that is all one string, there isn't a selector that will get only the text you want.  You'll have to grab the entire string, and use some other way to extract just the number, such as a regex, or a string parse method.

Comment: Well, attach html first. Second, using selenium get value in that field then parse it and extract number using simple string funcs.

Comment: html and your approach with a proper description where you are failing to get you question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the above pattern of the string remains same ie (Purchase Order 234 has been logged on 8/28/2014.) I have written the below code to get only 234 from the entire string.

```
String str = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath where the string is present on the webpage).getText() ;
```

//get the string from the web page and store it in string variable called str.

```
int res = 0;
        int count=0;

        for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c=='/')
            {
                break;
            }
            else
                {
                    count++;
                }
            System.out.println("count:"+count);
        }

        for (int i=0; i < count-1; i++)
        {
            char c1 = str.charAt(i);
            if (c1 < '0' || c1 > '9') 
            {
                System.out.println("continue : "+c1);
                continue;
            }
            res = res * 10 + (c1 - '0');
        }

            System.out.println(":"+res);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first for loop will go till '/' character and then we will loop through the string till the first '/' character is encountered. count-1 will skip the number 8 so that we will get res=234.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at js but here is example:

```
divText = driver.findElement(By.Css("#GD1")).getText();
divText.split(' ').forEach(function(word) {
if (word.search(/[^A-Za-z\s]/) != -1 && word.search(/[\/]/) == -1)
    console.log(word);
})
```